get a long error while install pip install dlib
when i install this
pip install dlib
it give a long error:
C:\Users\Hadi.M>pip install dlib
Collecting dlib
  Using cached dlib-19.24.6.tar.gz (3.4 MB)
Building wheels for collected packages: dlib
  Building wheel for dlib (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-no9dya16'
       cwd: C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\
  Complete output (51 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_ext
  Building extension for Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
  Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DDLIB_USE_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
  -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
  -- The C compiler identification is unknown
  -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



  CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
    No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 243, in <module>
      setup(
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
      dist.run_commands()
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
      self.run_command(cmd)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\wheel\_bdist_wheel.py", line 378, in run
      self.run_command("build")
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
      self.run_command(cmd_name)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
      self.distribution.run_command(command)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
      cmd_obj.run()
    File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 168, in run
      self.build_extension(ext)
    File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 206, in build_extension
      subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
    File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
      raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
  subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\hadi.m\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DDLIB_USE_FFMPEG=OFF', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for dlib
  Running setup.py clean for dlib
Failed to build dlib
Installing collected packages: dlib
    Running setup.py install for dlib ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mk3t2pzf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\dlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\
    Complete output (53 lines):
    running install
    running build
    running build_ext
    Building extension for Python 3.8.10 (tags/v3.8.10:3d8993a, May  3 2021, 11:48:03) [MSC v.1928 64 bit (AMD64)]
    Invoking CMake setup: 'cmake C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\tools\python -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -DDLIB_USE_FFMPEG=OFF -DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\build\lib.win-amd64-3.8 -A x64'
    -- Building for: Visual Studio 17 2022
    -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.22621.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
    -- The C compiler identification is unknown
    -- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_C_COMPILER could be found.



    CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:14 (project):
      No CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER could be found.



    -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 243, in <module>
        setup(
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 61, in run
        return orig.install.run(self)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 545, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\command\build.py", line 135, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 168, in run
        self.build_extension(ext)
      File "C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-coqhec1l\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\setup.py", line 206, in build_extension
        subprocess.check_call(cmake_setup, cwd=build_folder)
      File "c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['cmake', 'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\tools\\python', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY=C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=c:\\users\\hadi.m\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python38\\python.exe', '-DDLIB_USE_FFMPEG=OFF', '-DCMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY_RELEASE=C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\build\\lib.win-amd64-3.8', '-A', 'x64']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Hadi.M\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-coqhec1l\\dlib_22ddd70e8b3f40f79e9038231336c834\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\Hadi.M\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-mk3t2pzf\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Include\dlib' Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.1.1; however, version 24.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'c:\users\hadi.m\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.`

my python is 3.8.0
i want to install a githbu project. i get this error so i need to pip install dlib:
loading data No module named 'dlib'
